# "R" I want a linear decay response to impulse input without overlap from a subsequent impulse

Tags: r, filter

So I have a lot of sparse data in the form of:

```
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
```

and would like to see a response in the form of this:

```
0.5
0.75
1
0
0.25
0.5
0.75
1
0.75
1
0
```

I can easily write a function to do this, but the dataset it large enough that my computer can barely handle it and as such have been trying the filter command in R.

```
b <- apply(err_mat_first, 2, rev)
rm(err_mat_first)
filter_6m = (26300:1)/26300
d6 = filter(b, filter_6m, sides = 1)
damage_mat_6m<- apply(d6, 2, rev);
```

Unfortunately when I do this I get something on the order of:

```
0.5
0.75
1
0
0.25
0.5
1   (0.75+0.25)
1.5 (1+0.5)
0.75
1
0
```

I need to eliminate that region of overlap.  I have to believe that there is a type of filter in r which does this, but I can't find it.  Any suggestions?  Thank you very much.
-Rick

So here is the answer I went with.  It is nothing sexy, but it did the job.

```
err_mat_first<- read.csv(file="C:/thesis/WT_test_err_mat_first.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",");
ones_at<-which(err_mat_first==1,arr.in=T)
weighted_mat<-matrix(0,nrow(err_mat_first),ncol(err_mat_first),
                 dimnames = list(1:nrow(err_mat_first),c("toss",common_error_codes)))
vec_len<-ones_at[1,1]-1
vec_to_insert<-(1:vec_len)/vec_len
weighted_mat[(ones_at[1,1]-vec_len+1):(ones_at[1,1]),(ones_at[1,2])]<-vec_to_insert 

for (n in 2:nrow(ones_at))
{if (ones_at[n,2]==ones_at[n-1,2])
    {vec_len<-ones_at[n,1]-ones_at[n-1,1]}
else
    {vec_len<-ones_at[n,1]-1}
vec_to_insert<-(1:vec_len)/vec_len
weighted_mat[(ones_at[n,1]-vec_len+1):(ones_at[n,1]),(ones_at[n,2])]<-vec_to_insert 
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way, but at least this way I only had to loop a few thousand times rather than about a billion.